# Docker: How to persist data with Nginx Proxy Manager

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose, proxy

I'm running containers for front & backend using docker-compose, now I have implemented Proxy Management using the "Nginx Proxy Manager" image. What is really annoying though is the fact that everytime I want to re-deploy or make changes to the containers, I have to setup the Proxy Management Website again and again. Is there a way to persist all proxy hosts, domain redirections, username/password?

My docker compose service for the Nginx Management:

```
  nginx-manager:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '81:81'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
```

Folder structure of the image:
[image: Folder structure]

It seems to me like all the nginx stuff is saved inside the data folder, which I tried to save too, but everytime I re-deploy I get the SSL certificate is invalid, becausethe data folder settings are not synced with the letsencrypt ones. Besides the fact that I can't store the SSL certs on github.

I tried everything but nothing seemed to be best practice or useable in production